# Batch Script : How do i set a 2nd arguments in a CALL?

Tags: batch-file

```
for /f %%j in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
findstr /m /i "yoyoyo" %%j
    if !ERRORLEVEL! == 0 (
        set post=yoyoyo
        CALL postset.bat "yoyoyo" %%jj
    )
)
```

I'm trying to pass 2 arguments to a CALL
the first is going through but not the second.

*edit* my real problem was with the other batch, didn't use %1 and %2, my bad!

Comment: Works here for me; what happens when postset.bat only contains `echo %*` ?

Answer (score 2):

The code works well for me. When passing 2 or more parametes to the postset.bat I am able to print out %1 till %9 (if set) from postset.bat.

Comment: you are right it passes well... my mistake was in the other .bat in fact... i didn't use %1 %2...  (n00b me)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not passing the variable %%j but %%**jj**.......

As this doesn't exist a null-value (nothing) will be passed to the bat-file.

**Update:**

The ERRORLEVEL test doesn't work as intended due to the way variable expansion works so the bat-file is never called at all.

Use `if errorlevel 1` in stead.

Comment: But even if there is one j to much this isn't the problem as %% parameters takes only an one character variable name. The second j should appended to the expanded parameter